# Using oak as embedded

Tags: jackrabbit, jackrabbit-oak

I want to use oak in my project as embedded.For a start I wrote a test method. In my method I use the same code from this example here https://jackrabbit.apache.org/oak/docs/construct.html The code runs just fine but it does not terminate unless I shutdown repository:

```
((RepositoryImpl) repo).shutdown();
```

So in my project, not for the first time but ever time when I want to connect to repository I call

```
mongoClient = new MongoClient(host, port);  
DB db = mongoClient.getDB(dbName);  
Builder builder = new DocumentMK.Builder(); 
builder.setMongoDB(db); 
ns = builder.getNodeStore();    
Oak oak = new Oak(ns);  
Jcr jcr = new Jcr(oak); 
repo = jcr.createRepository();  
try {   
    session = repo.login(new SimpleCredentials("admin", "admin".toCharArray()));    
} 
catch (LoginException e) {
    ...
}
```

and in the end

```
session.logout(); 
((RepositoryImpl) repo).shutdown(); 
ns.dispose(); 
mongoClient.close();
```

1. Do I have to call createRepository() every time or just for the first time and then use another method to connect repository.
2. Is shuting down the repository needed?

Comment: what happens when your code calls session.logout() and returns?

Comment: return type of logout() is void.I dont get any errors.I am just asking is this right way to do it?Because there wasn't any repo shutdown in the jackrabbit oak site.

Answer (score 1):

> Do I have to call createRepository() every time or just for the first time and then use another method to connect repository.

You will have to create the repository for the first time and use the same for login thereon, provided you keep the repository object. In case you lose the repository, as in you shut down, you will have to start from the beginning.

> Is shutting down the repository needed?

As given in the [documentation](https://jackrabbit.apache.org/api/2.10/org/apache/jackrabbit/api/JackrabbitRepository.html#shutdown()), we need to do this for releasing the resources and persisting changes if any.